# Build target paths for cp out of underscore/dash delimited words in filenames

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have multiple files of the type:

```
Hello_World1_2020-01-01_10-10_Schema1.tar.gz
Hello_World2_2019-02-02_05-05_Schema2.tar.gz
```

available in the folder `/work/abc`

I want to generate a linux command to copy these files accordingly like:

```
/work/def/202001/Schema1/Hello_World1_2020-01-01_10-10_Schema1.tar.gz
```

and

```
/work/def/201902/Schema2/Hello_World2_2019-02-02_05-05_Schema2.tar.gz
```

The subfolder `YYYYMM` and `Schema1`/`Schema2` should be coming from the filename of the original file that is being copied.

Comment: @oguzismail

same extension, yes (tar.gz);

prefix is multiple

(Hello_World1, Hello_World2, Hello_World3)

Comment: Does the destination directory `YYYYMM/Schema[0-9]` already exist or not?

Answer (score 2):

One option is splitting filenames by underscores and dashes using `read` with a custom `IFS` value, and using resulting bits for building the target path. E.g.:

```
# to be run within /work/abc
for src in *.tar.gz; do
  IFS=_- read -r -d '' -a bits <<< "$src"
  dst="/work/def/${bits[-6]}${bits[-5]}/${bits[-1]%.tar.gz*}"
  # mkdir -p "$dst"
  echo cp -- "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Drop `echo` if its output looks good, and uncomment the line with `mkdir` if target directories don't already exist.

Note that this assumes each `.tar.gz` file in `/work/abc` have a `YYYY-mm-dd_HH-MM_schema` suffix where `schema` represents a string that does not contain underscores or dashes.

---

The regex based approach I mentioned in a comment below looks like:

```
re=".*_\
([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_\
(.*)\.tar\.gz"

for src in *.tar.gz; do
  if ! [[ $src =~ $re ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  printf -v dst '/work/def/%s%s/%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
  echo mkdir -p "$dst"
  echo cp -- "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the variables `srcdir` and `dstdirprefix` at the top of script. Also, you may want to drop the `-n` in `cp` command. Notice that the script will work for *all* filenames which contain a `_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_` pattern, and end with a `_[^.]*.tar.gz`, independent of number of intervening elements.

```
#!/bin/bash

srcdir=/work/abc
dstdirprefix=/work/def

cd "$srcdir" || exit

shopt -s nullglob

for file in *_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_*.tar.gz
do
    [[ $file =~ _([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2}_.*_([^.]*).tar.gz$ ]] || continue
    destdir=$dstdirprefix/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    mkdir -p "$destdir"
    cp -n "./$file" "$destdir/"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for file_name in *
do 
read -r  dt schema <<< $(echo $file_name | awk -F'_' '{split($NF, a, "."); print gensub("-" , "", "g" ,$3) ,a[1] } ' )
mv $file_name /work/def/"$dt"/"$schema"/"$file_name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @oguz

I had to make some updates since there were some `_` in `schema` name:

```
for src in *.tar.gz; do
  IFS=_- read -r -d '' -a bits <<< "$src"
 
  len=${#bits[@]}
  
  
  if [ $len == 9 ]
  then
    mkdir -p "/outputFolder/${bits[-7]}${bits[-6]}/${bits[-2]}_${bits[-1]%.tar.gz*}"
    cp "$src" \
    "/outputFolder/${bits[-7]}${bits[-6]}/${bits[-2]}_${bits[-1]%.tar.gz*}"
    
  else
    mkdir -p "/outputFolder/${bits[-6]}${bits[-5]}/${bits[-1]%.tar.gz*}"
    cp "$src" \
    "/outputFolder/${bits[-6]}${bits[-5]}/${bits[-1]%.tar.gz*}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Well done. If the prefix is always two words, you don't really need that if statement, you can use `IFS=-_ read -r -d'' _ _ year month _ _ _ schema` to read year, month, and schema into corresponding variables; and assign `dst="/work/def/$year$month/${schema%.tar.gz*}"` instead. If it is two or more words, a regex anchored at the date string would do a better job, M.Nejat's answer above uses a similar approach.